# Distribute Sysinternals free console program with my shareware application?

Tags: copyright, software, distribution-terms

I am a shareware author (more on the hobbyist level) and I would like to distribute the free SysInternals program [Sigcheck](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck) (a small console program) as a helper tool together with my program. Sigcheck would not perform the main part of my program's functionality, rather a secondary functionality, by fetching the console output of Sigcheck (for checking the security information of Windows/Microsoft programs).

Would it be enough to put the EULA of SigCheck inside the installed program directory where the SigCheck program file is located?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Sysinternals Licensing FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/license-faq):

Q: May I distribute Sysinternals utilities in my software, on my website, or with my magazine?
A: No. We are not offering any distribution licenses, even if the 3rd party is distributing them for free. We encourage people to download the utilities from our download center where they can be assured to get the most recent version of the utility.